# Chrome not loading Vimeo direct video URLs

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, html5-video, vimeo, akamai

I use the "direct download" URL's Vimeo Pro provides to play a MP4 video using the native <video> element.

The code that is used to display those videos is like this:

```
<video
 src="https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/816142354/rendition/720p/file.mp4?loc=external&signature=4a8aca453a2b639ef31242b4e86286da0c217f1e67991aa2b843dc3269bdf268" 
 id="videoPlayer" 
 controls 
 controlslist="nodownload" 
 disablepictureinpicture
>
</video>
```

The video on the website will not be loaded.

With the following error: GET https://download-video.akamaized.net/2/playback/..................... 403 Forbidden
[image]

When I clear the cache the video loads normally. But the next day the video won't load as before.

If anyone knows a solution, help me.

Comment: I have to same issue, started from couple days ago, I emailed Vimeo waiting for response also for now I disabled to header Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires, because its reading Vimeo url from cache lets see maybe it will be temporary solution

Comment: I got tihs: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1433305 from Vimeo Support. might be useful to you. @GirayKefelioglu

Comment: Thanks a lot for waiting, am Tamer from the API Support team,
 
After deeper investigation from our development team, They found out that a new Google Chrome Browser bug detected that we can't handle from our side and we need to wait for Google to release a fix for it, and our recommendation currently until they fix it to not using chrome or clearing caches/incognito mode of the browser, until they full fix and release a fix for it.
 
This the bug in Google Side : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1433305

Comment: Facing the same issue. At the bottom of the thread bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1433305 there is a suggestion that setting 'Cache-Control': 'no-store' should work as an interim fix. I'm assuming this means send that along as a header with your client request? However, when I do so I'm getting 'blocked by CORS policy error' reading 'en blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.' Have I misinterpreted the workaround? Thanks for your help.